# Showing Cycle is NL-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

Consider the following decision problem :

> Cycle:
>    Given a directed graph G, does G contains a directed cycle?

It is very clear why Cycle belongs to NL. 
My question is - how to show Cycle is also NL-hard?
it seems almost obvious to show logarithmic reduction from stCON. I thought about the following reduction:

> Given a tuple (G, s, t), return G with a new edge (t,s).

Comment: I think you mean the edge $(t,s)$. Anyway, it doesn't work: there might be a directed cycle in $G+st$ that has nothing at all to do with the $s$-$t$ path plus the edge $(t,s)$.  For example, suppose that $s$ and $t$ are in different components of $G$ and that one of them contains a directed cycle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us reduce direct connectivity to CYCLE.

We are given a directed graph $G$ and two vertices $s,t$. Suppose that $G$ contains $n$ vertices.

- We create $n$ copies of the vertices of $G$.
- For each edge $x \to y$ in $G$, we add an edge from the $i$th copy of $x$ to the $(i+1)$th copy of $y$.
- We also add an edge from each copy $i$ of $t$ to the first copy of $s$ (i.e. the edges $(t_i,s_1), i=1,...,n$).

The new graph contains a cycle iff $t$ is reachable from $s$ in $G$.

We can construct the new graph from the original graph in logspace. Hence this is a logspace reduction, which shows that CYCLE is NL-hard.

Comment: I think this reduction is not correct. It only works if there is a path from s to t of length *exactly* n. To fix this, we could add an edge from every copy of t to the first copy of s.