# Log space reduction from STCONN to CYCLE

Tags: reductions, space-complexity

I read this post: [Showing Cycle is NL-complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109972/showing-cycle-is-nl-complete?rq=1), but I am not sure why the reduction is log space, as it requires keeping track of the new graph, which has $n^2$ nodes.

Comment: The new graph has $O(n^2)$ nodes.

Comment: Thank you for correction. However, I am still not sure why it is a log space reduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to store the new graph on the tape. We just need to be able to output it in logspace. This is straightforward, for any reasonable encoding of graphs.

Comment: How can the new graph computed in log space?

Comment: As I said, it's straightforward, assuming you understand logspace computation well enough. There's no point in me spelling it out. All you have to do is be able to write a description of the new graph. You can do this using a few loops, with all loop variables being of logarithmic size (and linear or quadratic magnitude).